# How to train a classifier using list of list feature Python

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have two variables called entity and label. The entity variable store list of word, each element in this list contain list as well. So it is a list of list variable. This list actually a bi-gram feature so I need to keep it.

I try to train a classifier using this two variables. This my code so far:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

entity = [[['Prabowo Subianto']], [['Muhtar Ependi']], [['Nina Zatulini']], [['Partai Gerindra']], [['Persiba']], [['Partai Kebangkitan Bangsa (PKB)'], ['Partai Kebangkitan'], ['Kebangkitan Bangsa'], ['Bangsa ('], ['( PKB'], ['PKB )']], [['Sman 3 Kabupaten Tangerang'], ['Sman 3'], ['3 Kabupaten'], ['Kabupaten Tangerang']], [['Bandara Changi Singapura'], ['Bandara Changi'], ['Changi Singapura']], [['Warung Kopi Kita'], ['Warung Kopi'], ['Kopi Kita']]]
label = ['PERSON', 'PERSON', 'PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'ORGANIZATION', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION', 'LOCATION', 'LOCATION']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
train_vector_entity = vectorizer.fit_transform(entity)
train_vector_label = label

classifier = svm.SVC()
classifier_word = classifier.fit(train_vector_entity,train_vector_label)
```

The error result:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What is the best way to train the classifier?
Thanks

Comment: What does the list of list represent? I mean does it have any significance of keeping in list? Cant you iterate through it to make it a single list which can then be passed to `TfidfVectorizer`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this row:

```
train_vector_entity = vectorizer.fit_transform([i[0][0] for i in entity])
```